# MongoDB Large Generic Object Catalog. Is one large collection feasible?

Tags: mongodb

Overview

We are planning a general object storage catalog as our central data repository for all operations within our organization.
We have the basic framework of the system in place and are to the point where we need to decide on the object storage implementation.

Approach

Our basic design approach is to have multiple collections that contain metadata about the objects that are stored. Each collection will describe a different "group" of data.
Then, we will have a single GridFS that will store all of the objects. The idea is to have a single repository of all objects where each object can be described by 1 or more metadata record.

Our Concerns

We expect bursts of between 5-50 read and write operations per second. That would include 1 or more write to metadata collections and 1 to the GridFS per write and the same for reads.
There will be 25-50 million records in the GridFS object catalog at any one time.
The index on the GridFS will be a key-value-pair index on an array `{ Object-Metadata-Identity: [ {Record-Identifier: UUID}, {...}, ...] }` where the index will be on Record-Identifier.
Each record in the GridFS will have a varying size of between <1KB - 9GB where 90% of the data will be closer to the 1KB range.

Alternative Considerations

We have considered several other approaches including all combinations of the following:
separating the objects into multiple GridFS collections
using the hard drive for larger files
using regular collections for files that are less than 16MB

Basic Requirements

Our goal is to have a generic, extensible solution that is able to grow with our ever changing requirements.
The solution has to be fast because it is routing very time sensitive data.
The solution has to be reliable (three 9's) once it is production ready.

Summary

Our overall question is, can MongoDB support fast read/writes on a GridFS reliability with so many records, or are we going to need to explore some combination of other solutions to supplement object storage.

Comment: Kevin, I propose, that you get in touch with Mongo Inc. Assuming an average file size of 4,5GB * 50M records, we end up at 225.000TB (225PB?) - multiplied by 3 for replication and then we did not talk about backup yet. Read/Write performance is not a problem with MongoDB 3 with WiredTiger. GridFS is "just" a wrapper that does the correlation/chunking for you. Having all the data on a grid of NetApp's or something like that with storing only the meta data in MongoDB seems more feasible to me. Hadoop/HDFS might be a better option if you want to build a really huge FS with commodity hardware

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question that nearly 90% of the data will be in the 1K-5K range. We have been testing with a subset of our data to try to estimate total storage size. It is nearly impossible to estimate with any accuracy but assuming that we have about 10% of our data in Mongo so far we might be looking at a range of 500GB to possibly 1TB (or more).

Comment: Ok :-) 1TB is nothing to worry. Then you just should run a few performance and capacity tests against various hardware setups to verify you get the performance you need. You can go even for sharded GridFS (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-gridfs-data/), but your tests should show you, how the system behaves, perhaps only one ReplicaSet is sufficient. Having more read than write ops is great for MongoDB. More writes than reads might cause too much of locks (at least with MMAPv1), so the WiredTiger storage engine might fit better.

Comment: PS: Here's my MongoDB testing story https://www.paluch.biz/blog/124-finding-the-right-nosql-data-store-results-for-my-use-case-and-a-surprise.html